# Read/write external storage on Android

Tags: java, android, permissions, storage

I'm developing an Android application that reads and writes data in a `/sdcard/MyFolder` directory. I get the sdcard path trough the method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

I tested the application on a Samsung device where the path returned by the method is `/mnt/sdcard` on which I append `/MyFolder`; all works fine and I can r/w files in this folder. 
Now I'm trying to do the same on a Nexus device: I have put my files to read in the `/sdcard/MyFolder` directory and `getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns `/storage/emulated/0/` as path, on which I append `/MyFolder`. But in this case I cannot find the files to read.

I set all the storage permissions in the manifest.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any particular issue related to an emulated directory?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of android does your Nexus run? Android 6.0??

Comment: have you checked the errors ?

Comment: @SripadRaj Yes, 6.0, while the Samsung 4.0.4

Comment: @KunalK It throws a NullPointerException

Comment: NullPointerException at what? what is the cause ? check in detail or post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 6.0, you have to handle certain permissions at runtime. Please go through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Because `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are considered as dangerous permissions and has to be handled at runtime.